Not able to Unsave Jobs in a react/supabase based Job Portal Website
I am building a Job Portal Website from a youtube video => Full Stack React JS Project ( Job Portal ) - with Tailwind, Supabase, Clerk, Shadcn UI Tutorial, But i am stuck in a functionality When a user clicks the "Save Job" button, the job is successfully saved. However, when trying to unsave a job, it is not being removed from the saved jobs list. Instead, it appears to be added again.
The issue seems to be in alreadySaved where its value is undefined due to some reason and then it calls the else loop and adds the job
This is my saveJobs function =>
// - Add / Remove Saved Job
export async function saveJob(token, { alreadySaved }, saveData) {
  const supabase = await supabaseClient(token);

  if (alreadySaved) {
    // If the job is already saved, remove it
    const { data, error: deleteError } = await supabase
      .from("saved_jobs")
      .delete()
      .eq("job_id", saveData.job_id);

    if (deleteError) {
      console.error("Error removing saved job:", deleteError);
      return data;
    }

    return data;
  } else {
    // If the job is not saved, add it to saved jobs
    const { data, error: insertError } = await supabase
      .from("saved_jobs")
      .insert([saveData])
      .select();

    if (insertError) {
      console.error("Error saving job:", insertError);
      return data;
    }

    return data;
  }
}

And i am calling this function in JobsCard.jsx =>
const JobCard = ({
  job,
  savedInit = false,
  onJobAction = () => {},
  isMyJob = false,
}) => {
  const [saved, setSaved] = useState(savedInit);

  const { user } = useUser();

  const { loading: loadingDeleteJob, fn: fnDeleteJob } = useFetch(deleteJob, {
    job_id: job.id,
  });

  const {
    loading: loadingSavedJob,
    data: savedJob,
    fn: fnSavedJob,
  } = useFetch(saveJob);

  const handleSaveJob = async () => {
    await fnSavedJob({
      user_id: user.id,
      job_id: job.id,
    });
    onJobAction();
  };

  const handleDeleteJob = async () => {
    await fnDeleteJob();
    onJobAction();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (savedJob !== undefined) setSaved(savedJob?.length > 0);
  }, [savedJob]);

In my supabase i have created saved_jobs table with the fields as id, created_at , user_id and job_id ( foreign key from jobs table)
I have enabled appropritae row level policy as well
For reference this is the working code that the youtuber created - GitHub Repo
I tried adding a field already saved in my database but it did not worked
